# Multidimensional unserialized Array - extract data - count extracted data and sort A-Z

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => a:7:{s:21:"mage_form_post_status";s:5:"draft";s:19:"mage_form_post_type";s:4:"post";s:25:"mage_form_post_permission";s:6:"public";s:21:"mage_form_post_author";s:1:"1";s:23:"mage_form_post_redirect";s:1:"0";s:19:"mage_form_post_edit";b:0;} 
[1] => a:4:{s:14:"mage_your_name";s:14:"George Jackson";s:15:"mage_your_email";s:24:"amy.thompson41@gmail.com";s:13:"mage_who_name";s:8:"Gym Goer";s:10:"mage_video";s:0:"";} 
[2] => a:7:{s:21:"mage_form_post_status";s:5:"draft";s:19:"mage_form_post_type";s:3:"gym";s:25:"mage_form_post_permission";s:6:"public";s:21:"mage_form_post_author";s:1:"1";s:23:"mage_form_post_redirect";s:2:"88";s:19:"mage_form_post_edit";b:0;}
[3] => a:2:{s:15:"mage_tags_input";s:0:"";s:14:"mage_your_name";s:5:"Denis";} 
[4] => a:1:{s:14:"mage_your_name";s:5:"Denis";}
[5] => a:2:{s:13:"mage_gym_name";s:12:"Fanna - test";s:14:"mage_your_name";s:4:"John";} 
[7] => a:2:{s:13:"mage_gym_name";s:11:"Boss - test";s:14:"mage_your_name";s:4:"Rudy";} 
[8] => a:6:{s:21:"mage_form_post_status";s:5:"draft";s:19:"mage_form_post_type";s:4:"post";s:25:"mage_form_post_permission";s:11:"contributor";s:21:"mage_form_post_author";i:0;s:20:"mage_form_post_email";s:0:"";s:23:"mage_form_post_redirect";i:0;} 
[9] => a:2:{s:13:"mage_gym_name";s:11:"Batt - test";s:14:"mage_your_name";s:3:"Ann";} 
[10] => a:2:{s:13:"mage_gym_name";s:11:"Boss - test";s:14:"mage_your_name";s:6:"Freddy";} 
)
```

I would like to display result like this in A-Z order:

Batt - test (1)

Boss - test (2)

Fanna - test (1)

Can you please help me?

Comment: So what have you tried to do. So **is not a free coding service**

Comment: `array_map('unserialize', $arr)` and work as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `array_map`, `unserialize`, `array_column`(available since PHP 5.5), `array_count_values` and `ksort` functions:

```
// $serialized_data is your initial array

$unserialized = array_map('unserialize', $serialized_data);
$gym_names = array_column($unserialized, 'mage_gym_name');  // getting all 'mage_gym_name' entries
$counts = array_count_values($gym_names);
ksort($counts);  // sorting by keys

print_r($counts);
```

The output will be alike to the following:

```
Array
(
    [Batt - test] => 1
    [Boss - test] => 2
    ....
)
```

Comment: I am triyng to implement your code and  this part of code is breaking the rest of code:  array_column($unserialized, 'mage_gym_name');

Comment: I have wrote *available since PHP 5.5* - check your PHP version

Comment: You are absolutely right, my hosting is using PHP 5.4.45 version

Comment: will you ask your hosting provider to upgrade PHP to at least 5.6 version? (PHP 7 already available) Your "PHP" is getting old

Comment: I didn't know that this is an option and already started to look for Polifil function for older PHP version. https://gist.github.com/TorbenKoehn/5866154

Comment: When I use this Polyfill everything works as You have show me. I am going to mark your answer as correct one. Thank You a lot ROMAN.